# Cannot find control with path: 'data -> 1 -> value'

Tags: angular

I need to create as many input fields as there are records in my array.

I am getting the following error when trying to do this:

> Cannot find control with path: 'data -> 1 -> value'

How to fix it?

**html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngIf="subCategoriesParams$ | async as subCategoryParams">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let params of subCategoryParams.params; let i = index" 
            formArrayName="data">
            <div formGroupName="{{i}}">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label">
                        {{params.paramsName}}
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="value" 
                        (change)="onChangeEvent(params)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

**ts:**

```
  public get data() {
    return this.form.get('data') as FormArray;
  }

  initializeForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      data: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          params: [this.inp, Validators.required],
          category: [this.selectedDescendants, Validators.required],
          value: ['', Validators.required],
        })
      ])
    });
  }

  loadParams() {
    this.subCategoriesParams$ = 
          this.categoryService.findOne(this.selectedDescendants);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue & Concern

You are iterating `i` (formGroupName) based on `subCategoryParams.params` but not based on `formArray`.

And from the above code, I don't see any (`FormGroup`) value being initialized to `data` (`FormArray`).

Hence, let's say `subCategoryParams.params` with length: 3, while `data` with length of 0. That's why you faced the error mentioned.

---

### Solution

Make sure your `data` (`FormArray`) length must be exact with the length of `subCategoryParams.params` by adding `FormGroup` instance to `FormArray`.

```js
initializeForm(): void {
  ...

  this.subCategoriesParams$.forEach((value) => {
    for (let param of value.params) {
      this.data.push(
        this.fb.group({
          params: [this.inp, Validators.required],
          category: [this.selectedDescendants, Validators.required],
          value: ['', Validators.required],
        })
      );
    }
  });
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6yiwhg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Note:**

1. For safer (real answer), you have to iterate over `data.controls` (`FormArray`).
2. Below solution is just to fix in case you are keen to iterate over `subCategoryParams.params`.

Comment: The solution really is iterate over `data.controls`.

Comment: Ya, by right (safe) have to iterate over `data.controls`. But Post Owner's requirement is to generate based on that observable value and need to access value like `params.paramsName`.

Comment: I want to say that always is better iterate over data.controls, because in this way always has the "formGroups", else you can has value in subCategoriesParams before initialize the form. But yes, your code show how create a formArray based in an array of elements (that's great!)

Comment: Ya, I had updated my answer for the suggestion. And sorry for misunderstanding your previous comment. And thanks again for giving the feedback. =)